# Where can I find a good and concise Android development tutorial for an intermediate Java Developer?

Tags: java, android

I am an intermediate level Java programmer (with more experience in C# and PHP), and I am interested in learning the basics of Android Development. My problem currently is that I have a long commute to work which means that I effectively have only 2 or 3 hours a week I can spend on "for fun" programming.

Given my circumstance, what I could really use is a tutorial that is descriptive enough to help me understand the different components of an Android App, while still being concise enough to allow me to read and attempt to implement some ideas of my own in small chunks.

Normally I would just invest the time in Google, but I figure that I will get much better results from a community of those who have been through a similar search. Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link is a series of YouTube Videos which is a full boot camp teaching good coding practices and what not. Throughout the video he constructs a full Twitter app as a demo. Good demonstration of the Activity Life Cycle, good practices and such.

[Android Bootcamp](http://www.youtube.com/user/MarakanaTechTV#p/c/E953C0B85B50AB62/17/FP2gElnwTSs)

Comment: This is pretty much what I was looking for. The episodes are a little longer than I have continuous time for, but half of the first video was already enough to vastly improve my understanding of basic Android development.

Comment: I was very happy when I finally found this. The videos from the Google IO conference are also good, if a little more scattered.

Answer (score 0):

[Hello world](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html) will get you bootstrapped.  After mastering Activities, googling for tutorials for Intents and Services will cover the other two main topics.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/index.html) to understand the basics and then started to learn on the sample code of Android.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the offical site for the same, it has a basic set of well thought out tutorials: http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=tutorial

This one is quite lengthy and presumes basic dev knowledge but still explains things nicely including setting up of the dev environment (Eclipse IDE):
http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html

If you want video then nothing quite like youtube, this one and related parts / videos cover only basics:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pqK2T_J1c98

Answer (score 0):

makarana guys have real good tutorials. I also signed up for http://codelesson.com but it seems expensive